# Convert Nested case statement to decode

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Case when a.startdate = b.startdate and a.enddate <> b.enddate then 1
     When a.idcount = b.idcount and a.id dte <> b.iddte then 1
     else 0
end
```

Convert this case statement to decode statement
Please help to convert this statement

Comment: Hm, how to convert an **invalid** CASE statement into anything? Apart from that, why would you want to do that? DECODE would be *worse* than CASE because CASE is easy to read and maintain; DECODE, with multiple options, is a **nightmare**.

Comment: Why bother? Keep this case expression.

Comment: `DECODE` is acceptable, in my view, when the logic is very terse and it saves typing. A simple equality comparison, for example, or as it was intended, a mapping of a list of values to a corresponding list of values, for which `CASE` would require a lot more typing. But for any kind of compound logic, inequalities, fallback conditions, etc... definitely use `CASE`.

Comment: Unless you have to run something in 8i like I do, which doesn't support `CASE` in SQL :) Then you just get creative with `DECODE` which does in fact get rather ugly. Hopefully not too many folks have to worry about 8i anymore.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert it, just use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE
WHEN a.startdate = b.startdate
AND  a.enddate <> b.enddate
THEN 1
WHEN a.idcount = b.idcount
AND  a.iddte <> b.iddte
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

If you are using it in a `ON` clause of a join (or a `WHERE` clause) then don't use `CASE` or `DECODE`, just directly use the expressions with `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_a a
       INNER JOIN table_b b
       ON (  (a.startdate = b.startdate AND a.enddate <> b.enddate)
          OR (a.idcount = b.idcount AND a.iddte <> b.iddte))
```

---

If you did want to change it to `DECODE` then:

```sql
CASE WHEN a.startdate = b.startdate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

can be rewritten as:

```sql
DECODE(a.startdate, b.startdate, 1, 0)
```

Expanding it to two comparisons then:

```sql
CASE WHEN a.startdate = b.startdate AND a.enddate <> b.enddate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Converting `<>` to comparisons based on `=` and `IS NULL` would be the same as:

```sql
CASE
WHEN a.startdate = b.startdate
THEN CASE
     WHEN a.enddate IS NULL
     THEN 0
     WHEN a.enddate = b.enddate
     THEN 0
     ELSE CASE
          WHEN b.enddate IS NULL
          THEN 0
          ELSE 1
          END
     END
ELSE 0
END
```

Which can be implemented as:

```sql
DECODE(
  a.startdate,
  b.startdate,
  DECODE(
    a.enddate,
    NULL,
    0,
    b.enddate,
    0,
    DECODE(b.enddate, NULL, 0, 1)
  ),
  0
)
```

This is the equivalent `DECODE` for the first `WHEN` clause of the `CASE` expression and it will get even more complicated when you add in the second clause. That hopefully gives you some idea of why you should not try to use `DECODE` for this.

But continuing onwards, the second `WHEN` clause can be implemented as per the first with different identifiers:

```sql
DECODE(
  a.idcount,
  b.idcount,
  DECODE(
    a.iddte,
    NULL,
    0,
    b.iddte,
    0,
    DECODE(b.iddte, NULL, 0, 1)
  ),
  0
)
```

Then everywhere there is a `0` in the first `DECODE` expression, replace it with the second `DECODE`:

```sql
DECODE(
  a.startdate,
  b.startdate,
  DECODE(
    a.enddate,
    NULL,
    DECODE(
      a.idcount,
      b.idcount,
      DECODE(
        a.iddte,
        NULL,
        0,
        b.iddte,
        0,
        DECODE(b.iddte, NULL, 0, 1)
      ),
      0
    ),
    b.enddate,
    DECODE(
      a.idcount,
      b.idcount,
      DECODE(
        a.iddte,
        NULL,
        0,
        b.iddte,
        0,
        DECODE(b.iddte, NULL, 0, 1)
      ),
      0
    ),
    DECODE(
      b.enddate,
      NULL,
      DECODE(
        a.idcount,
        b.idcount,
        DECODE(
          a.iddte,
          NULL,
          0,
          b.iddte,
          0,
          DECODE(b.iddte, NULL, 0, 1)
        ),
        0
      ),
      1
    )
  ),
  DECODE(
    a.idcount,
    b.idcount,
    DECODE(
      a.iddte,
      NULL,
      0,
      b.iddte,
      0,
      DECODE(b.iddte, NULL, 0, 1)
    ),
    0
  )
)
```

Really, don't use `DECODE` for this.